# How do I access Cosmos DB database or collection metrics via the Azure REST API?

Tags: azure, azure-cosmosdb, azure-resource-manager

I am attempting to use the Azure metrics API to retrieve metrics for Cosmos DB databases and collections.

I am able to use the metrics API to retrieve metrics for the Cosmos DB account itself, but I cannot figure out the resource URL for the databases or collections.

So this works:

```
public static async Task GetMetricsForCollection(ICosmosDBAccount cosmos, IDocumentClient client)
{   
    var uriBuilder = new System.Text.StringBuilder();

    uriBuilder.Append($"https://management.azure.com{cosmos.Id}");
    uriBuilder.Append($"/providers/microsoft.insights/metricDefinitions?api-version=2018-01-01");

    //...Use uri to access API over HTTP
```

But I can't figure out how to get more specific metrics at deeper levels.

I [found this post on the MSDN Community](https://social.msdn.microsoft.com/Forums/en-US/2c078291-a99f-493b-98ce-f255a7975f5d/retrieve-programatic-collection-based-metrics) that says that this should work

```
public static async Task GetMetricsForCollection(ICosmosDBAccount cosmos, IDocumentClient client)
{
    var db = client.CreateDatabaseQuery().AsEnumerable().First();

    var uriBuilder = new System.Text.StringBuilder();
    //Use the database resource Id to retrieve the metrics
    uriBuilder.Append($"https://management.azure.com{cosmos.Id}/databases/{db.ResourceId}");
    uriBuilder.Append($"/providers/microsoft.insights/metricDefinitions?api-version=2018-01-01");

    //...Use uri to access API over HTTP
```

But it returns an error

```
Response status code does not indicate success: 400 
Microsoft.DocumentDB/databaseAccounts/databases is not a supported platform metric namespace, supported ones are 
Microsoft.LocationBasedServices/accounts,Microsoft.EventHub/namespaces,Microsoft.EventHub/clusters,Microsoft.ServiceBus/namespaces,
Microsoft.KeyVault/vaults,Microsoft.ClassicCompute/domainNames/slots/roles,Microsoft.ClassicCompute/virtualMachines,
Microsoft.Network/publicIPAddresses,Microsoft.Network/networkInterfaces,Microsoft.Network/loadBalancers,
Microsoft.Network/networkWatchers/connectionMonitors,Microsoft.Network/virtualNetworkGateways,Microsoft.Network/connections,
Microsoft.Network/applicationGateways,Microsoft.Network/dnszones,Microsoft.Network/trafficmanagerprofiles,
Microsoft.Network/expressRouteCircuits,Microsoft.EventGrid/eventSubscriptions,Microsoft.EventGrid/topics,Microsoft.EventGrid/extensionTopics,
Microsoft.Batch/batchAccounts,Microsoft.TimeSeriesInsights/environments,Microsoft.TimeSeriesInsights/environments/eventsources,
Microsoft.OperationalInsights/workspaces,Microsoft.Maps/accounts,Microsoft.Sql/servers,Microsoft.Sql/servers/databases,
Microsoft.Sql/servers/elasticpools,Microsoft.AnalysisServices/servers,Microsoft.Compute/virtualMachines,
Microsoft.Compute/virtualMachineScaleSets,Microsoft.Compute/virtualMachineScaleSets/virtualMachines,Microsoft.DataFactory/dataFactories,
Microsoft.DataFactory/factories,Microsoft.Storage/storageAccounts,Microsoft.Storage/storageAccounts/blobServices,
Microsoft.Storage/storageAccounts/tableServices,Microsoft.Storage/storageAccounts/queueServices,
Microsoft.Storage/storageAccounts/fileServices,Microsoft.Logic/workflows,Microsoft.Automation/automationAccounts,
Microsoft.ContainerService/managedClusters,Microsoft.StorageSync/storageSyncServices,Microsoft.ApiManagement/service,
Microsoft.DBforMySQL/servers,Microsoft.DocumentDB/databaseAccounts,Microsoft.ContainerRegistry/registries,Microsoft.Search/searchServices,
microsoft.insights/components,microsoft.insights/autoscalesettings,Microsoft.DataLakeStore/accounts,Microsoft.Web/serverFarms,
Microsoft.Web/sites,Microsoft.Web/sites/slots,Microsoft.Web/hostingEnvironments/multiRolePools,Microsoft.Web/hostingEnvironments/workerPools,
Microsoft.HDInsight/clusters,Microsoft.NetApp/netAppAccounts/capacityPools,Microsoft.NetApp/netAppAccounts/capacityPools/volumes,
test.shoebox/testresources,test.shoebox/testresources2,Microsoft.NotificationHubs/namespaces/notificationHubs,Microsoft.CustomerInsights/hubs,
CloudSimple.PrivateCloudIaaS/virtualMachines,Microsoft.StreamAnalytics/streamingjobs,Microsoft.CognitiveServices/accounts,
Microsoft.Cache/Redis,Microsoft.Devices/IotHubs,Microsoft.Devices/ElasticPools,Microsoft.Devices/ElasticPools/IotHubTenants,
Microsoft.Devices/ProvisioningServices,Microsoft.SignalRService/SignalR,Microsoft.DataLakeAnalytics/accounts,
Microsoft.DBforPostgreSQL/servers,Microsoft.ContainerInstance/containerGroups,Microsoft.Relay/namespaces,
Microsoft.PowerBIDedicated/capacities
```

(So you don't have to read all of that, I can confirm that it doesn't mention collections or databases as being usable with this API.)

I've also tried it with `db.Id` instead of `db.ResourceId` with the same error.

I've also tried going to the collection with `uriBuilder.Append($"https://management.azure.com{cosmos.Id}/databases/{db.ResourceId}/collections/{collection.ResourceId}");` but it also generates the same message.

I'm stumped.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

After poking around a bit with network traces while exploring in the Azure Portal, it looks like there are two types of Cosmos metrics: those that use the `microsoft.insights` provider and those that don't.

For those that use the provider, you can add the database and collection (the human readable names, aka the .Id property) as filters to the metrics API:

```
public static async Task GetMetricsForCollection(ICosmosDBAccount cosmos, IDocumentClient client)
{
    var db = client.CreateDatabaseQuery().AsEnumerable().First();
    var dbUri = UriFactory.CreateDatabaseUri(db.Id);
    var collection = client.CreateDocumentCollectionQuery(dbUri).AsEnumerable().First();

    var uriBuilder = new System.Text.StringBuilder();
    //Use the database resource Id to retrieve the metrics
    uriBuilder.Append($"https://management.azure.com{cosmos.Id}");
    uriBuilder.Append($"/providers/microsoft.insights/metricDefinitions?api-version=2018-01-01");
    uriBuilder.Append($"&$filter=DatabaseName eq '{db.Id}' and CollectionName eq '{collection.Id}'");
```

For those that don't, you can add `/metrics` to the resource URI suggested by the linked forum post. In this case, you need to use the `.ResourceId` properties.

It also looks like a `filter` parameter is required. I'm just copying and pasting from the Azure portal's network traces as I don't believe this is documented anywhere but it ends up looking something like

```
public static async Task GetMetricsForCollection(ICosmosDBAccount cosmos, IDocumentClient client)
{
    var db = client.CreateDatabaseQuery().AsEnumerable().First();
    var dbUri = UriFactory.CreateDatabaseUri(db.Id);
    var collection = client.CreateDocumentCollectionQuery(dbUri).AsEnumerable().First();

    var uriBuilder = new System.Text.StringBuilder();

    uriBuilder.Append($"https://management.azure.com{cosmos.Id}");
    uriBuilder.Append($"/databases/{db.ResourceId}/collections/{collection.ResourceId}/metrics?api-version=2014-04-01");
    uriBuilder.Append($"&$filter=(name.value eq 'Available Storage' or name.value eq 'Data Size' or name.value eq 'Index Size') and endTime eq 2018-06-22T12%3A35%3A00.000Z and startTime eq 2018-06-22T11%3A35%3A00.000Z and timeGrain eq duration'PT5M'");
```